# How to check if default value for python function argument is set using inspect?

Tags: python, signature, inspect

I'm trying to identify the parameters of a function for which default values are not set. I'm using `inspect.signature(func).parameters.value()` function which gives a list of function parameters. Since I'm using PyCharm, I can see that the parameters for which the default value is not set have their `Parameter.default` attribute set to `inspect._empty`. I'm declaring the function in the following way:

```py
def f(a, b=1):
    pass
```

So, the default value of `a` is `inspect._empty`. Since `inspect._empty` is a private attribute, I thought that there might be a method for checking if a value is `inspect._empty`, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import inspect


def foo(a, b=1):
    pass


for param in inspect.signature(foo).parameters.values():
    if param.default is param.empty:
        print(param.name)
```

Output:

```
a
```

`param.empty` holds the same object `inspect._empty`. I suppose that this way of using it is recommended because of the example in the [official documentation of inspect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter):

```
Example: print all keyword-only arguments without default values:

>>>
>>> def foo(a, b, *, c, d=10):
...     pass

>>> sig = signature(foo)
>>> for param in sig.parameters.values():
...     if (param.kind == param.KEYWORD_ONLY and
...                        param.default is param.empty):
...         print('Parameter:', param)
Parameter: c
```