# How to use inspect.signature to check that a function needs one and only one parameter?

Tags: python, signature, introspection

I want to validate (at runtime, this is not a typing question), that a function passed as an argument takes only 1 positional variable (basically that function will be called with a string as input and returns a truthy).

Naively, this is what I had:

```
def check(v_in : Callable):
    """check that the function can be called with 1 positional parameter supplied"""
    sig = signature(v_in)
    len_param = len(sig.parameters)
    if not len_param == 1:
        raise ValueError(
            f"expecting 1 parameter, of type `str` for {v_in}.  got {len_param}"
        )
    return v_in
```

If I check the following function, it is OK, which is good:

```
def f_ok1_1param(v : str):
    pass
```

but the next fails, though the `*args` would receive 1 param just fine and `**kwargs` would be empty

```
def f_ok4_vargs_kwargs(*args,**kwargs):
    pass
```

```
from rich import inspect as rinspect

try:
    check(f_ok1_1param)
    print("\n\npasses:") 
    rinspect(f_ok1_1param, title=False,docs=False)

except (Exception,) as e: 
    print("\n\nfails:") 
    rinspect(f_ok1_1param, title=False,docs=False)

try:
    check(f_ok4_vargs_kwargs)
    print("\n\npasses:") 
    rinspect(f_ok4_vargs_kwargs, title=False,docs=False)
except (Exception,) as e: 
    print("\n\nfails:") 
    rinspect(f_ok4_vargs_kwargs, title=False,docs=False)
```

which passes the first, and fails the second, instead of passing both:

```
passes:
╭─────────── <function f_ok1_1param at 0x1013c0f40> ───────────╮
│ def f_ok1_1param(v: str):                                    │
│                                                              │
│ 37 attribute(s) not shown. Run inspect(inspect) for options. │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯


fails:
╭──────── <function f_ok4_vargs_kwargs at 0x101512200> ────────╮
│ def f_ok4_vargs_kwargs(*args, **kwargs):                     │
│                                                              │
│ 37 attribute(s) not shown. Run inspect(inspect) for options. │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

all the different combination of signatures are defined below:

```
def f_ok1_1param(v : str):
    pass

def f_ok2_1param(v):
    pass

def f_ok3_vargs(*v):
    pass

def f_ok4_p_vargs(p, *v):
    pass

def f_ok4_vargs_kwargs(*args,**kwargs):
    pass

def f_ok5_p_varg_kwarg(param,*args,**kwargs):
    pass

def f_bad1_2params(p1, p2):
    pass

def f_bad2_kwargs(**kwargs):
    pass

def f_bad3_noparam():
    pass
```

Now, I did already check a bit more about the Parameters:

```
rinspect(signature(f_ok4_vargs_kwargs).parameters["args"])
╭─────────────────── <class 'inspect.Parameter'> ───────────────────╮
│ Represents a parameter in a function signature.                   │
│                                                                   │
│ ╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │ <Parameter "*args">                                           │ │
│ ╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
│                                                                   │
│          KEYWORD_ONLY = <_ParameterKind.KEYWORD_ONLY: 3>          │
│                  kind = <_ParameterKind.VAR_POSITIONAL: 2>        │
│                  name = 'args'                                    │
│       POSITIONAL_ONLY = <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_ONLY: 0>       │
│ POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD = <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1> │
│           VAR_KEYWORD = <_ParameterKind.VAR_KEYWORD: 4>           │
│        VAR_POSITIONAL = <_ParameterKind.VAR_POSITIONAL: 2>        │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

I suppose checking `Parameter.kind` vs `_ParameterKind` enumeration of each parameter is how this needs to be approached, but I wonder if I am overthinking this or if something already exists to do this, either in `inspect` or if the `typing` `protocol` support can be used to do, *but at runtime*.

Note, theoretically `def f_ok_cuz_default(p, p2 = None):` would also work, but let's ignore that for now.

p.s. The motivation is providing a custom callback function in a validation framework.  The call location is deep in the framework and that particular argument can also be a string (which gets converted to a regex). It can even be None.  Easiest here is just to stick a `def myfilter(*args,**kwargs):  breakpoint`.  Or `myfilter(foo)`.  Then look at what you get from the framework and adjust body.  It’s one thing to have exceptions *in* your function, another for the framework to *accept* it but then error *before* calling into it. So a quick “will this work when we call it?” is more user friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your problem is trivial, at all. And I am not aware of any given implementation, so I followed your train of thoughts and came to the conclusion that in the end, the problem boils down to answering the following questions:

1. Does the callable have any arguments, at all?
2. If so, is the first argument *positional*?
3. If so, are all other arguments *optional*?

If you answer all questions with yes, then your
function can be called with exactly one (positional) argument, otherwise not. In this context,

- *positional* means:

  - a single positional-or-keyword argument, as in `f(a)`, or
  - a single positional-only argument, as in `f(a, /)`, or
  - a variable list of positional arguments, as in `f(*args)`;
- *optional* means:

  - a variable list of positional arguments, as in `f(a, *args)`, or
  - a variable mapping of keyword arguments, as in `f(a, **kwargs)`, or
  - an argument with a default value, as in `f(a, b=None)`.

### Implementation

You can implement the corresponding check as follows:

```py
from inspect import Parameter, signature
from typing import Callable

def _is_positional(param: Parameter) -> bool:
    return param.kind in [
        Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD,
        Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY,
        Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL]

def _is_optional(param: Parameter) -> bool:
    return (param.kind in [
        Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL,
        Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD] or
        param.default is not Parameter.empty)

def has_one_positional_only(fct: Callable) -> bool:
    args = list(signature(fct).parameters.values())
    return (len(args) > 0 and  # 1. We have one or more args
            _is_positional(args[0]) and  # 2. First is positional
            all(_is_optional(a) for a in args[1:]))  # 3. Others are optional
```

### Test cases

This will return the correct results for your test cases (which I extended a bit):

```py
def f_ok1_1param(v : str): pass
def f_ok2_1param(v): pass
def f_ok3_vargs(*v): pass
def f_ok4_p_vargs(p, *v): pass
def f_ok4_vargs_kwargs(*args, **kwargs): pass
def f_ok5_p_varg_kwarg(param,*args,**kwargs): pass
def f_ok6_pos_only(v, /): pass  # also ok: explicitly positional only
def f_ok7_defaults(p, d=None): pass  # also ok: with default value
def f_bad1_2params(p1, p2): pass
def f_bad2_kwargs(**kwargs): pass
def f_bad3_noparam(): pass
def f_bad4_kwarg_after_args(*args, v): pass  # also not ok: v after *args is keyword-only
def f_bad5_kwarg_only(*, v): pass  # also not ok: explicitly keyword-only

print(has_one_positional_only(f_ok1_1param))             # True
print(has_one_positional_only(f_ok2_1param))             # True
print(has_one_positional_only(f_ok3_vargs))              # True
print(has_one_positional_only(f_ok4_p_vargs))            # True
print(has_one_positional_only(f_ok5_p_varg_kwarg))       # True
print(has_one_positional_only(f_ok6_pos_only))           # True
print(has_one_positional_only(f_ok7_defaults))           # True
print(has_one_positional_only(f_bad1_2params))           # False
print(has_one_positional_only(f_bad2_kwargs))            # False
print(has_one_positional_only(f_bad3_noparam))           # False
print(has_one_positional_only(f_bad4_kwarg_after_args))  # False
print(has_one_positional_only(f_bad5_kwarg_only))        # False
```

Two final thoughts:

1. At first I thought that the 2nd question needs to be formulated more generally, namely: Is *any* argument positional? However, I did not come up with any combination where it is not the first argument that must be the positional one (according to the given definition of *positional*, that is), and I am quite confident it is not possible with current Python syntax rules.
2. The solution for sure is not the most efficient one, given that with the knowledge about the parameters that you already checked, certain others are impossible to follow and thus actually don't need to be checked again (e.g. if the first optional argument was `**kwargs` then an optional `*args` cannot follow, any more).

**Update** for clarification: The provided solution will "work" in the sense that it checks whether a given callable's *signature* is compatible with calling it with exactly one positional argument. What it *cannot* ensure is that one given positional argument satisfies the *internal logic* of the callable. For example, if `f(*args)` internally tries to access an element after the 1st element in `args`, it will fail if called with one argument only, even though the proposed check lets it pass. There is not much to do to check the internal logic from the outside this way, other than running the callable or inspecting its actual code. (Also, to my understanding, the latter is not asked for in the question.)

Comment: Nice work.  I added your own test cases to mine (I had added more along the way) and everything is checked as expected.    I was a bit stumped with `f_bad4_kwarg_after_args(*args, v)` which looked like it should be accepted until I tried calling `f_bad4_kwarg_after_args("abc")` and got an error.

Answer (score 1):

I also wrote my own function after posting this.  I've cribbed default handling from the accepted answer (and cleaner `.kind` checks from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64427884/1394353)) but my approach was different in that I exit the inspect loop as soon as I know there are no *required positionals* following.

Surprisingly complex *and* hard to generalize from.  Something checking another signature (say 2 positionals this time) would have to redo most of it.

```
def _check_function_has_one_parameter(v_in : Callable) -> bool:
    """check that only NEED to provide one and only one positional"""

    count = 0
    for param in signature(v_in).parameters.values():
        pkind = param.kind

        #standard parameters
        if pkind in (param.POSITIONAL_ONLY,param.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD):
            if param.default is param.empty or not count:
                #first positional or any w.o. default 
                count += 1
            else:
                #positionals following will have also defaults 
                break
            
        #BREAK as we know we are done with positionals once we hit these...
        elif pkind == param.VAR_POSITIONAL:
            #but first, we'll count it as a positional if its the first...
            count = 1 if count == 0 else count
            break
        elif pkind in (param.KEYWORD_ONLY, param.VAR_KEYWORD):
            break
        else:
            #shouldn't happen, but...
            raise TypeError(f" unknown {pkind}")


    return count == 1
```